# MySQL Syntax Issue combining to working queries

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm just starting to learn SQL, and managed to cobble together a couple of working queries, but then when I combine them I am getting a syntax error.  The query throwing the error:

```
SELECT sca_ticket_status.name As Status, AVG(QueueTime) 
FROM (SELECT DateDiff (created, now()) as 'QueueTime'
FROM sca_ticket as SubQuery 
LEFT JOIN sca_ticket_status
ON sca_ticket.status_id = sca_ticket_status.id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY sort
```

For reference, the two working queries that I am attempting to leverage are as follows:

```
SELECT sca_ticket_status.name As Status, COUNT(sca_ticket.ticket_id) AS Count 
FROM sca_ticket
LEFT JOIN sca_ticket_status
ON sca_ticket.status_id = sca_ticket_status.id
WHERE sca_ticket.created between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY sort

SELECT AVG(QueueTime)
FROM (SELECT DateDiff (created, now()) as 'QueueTime'
FROM `sca_ticket`
WHERE `status_id` = 1) as SubQuery
```

Comment: Hey there. Please make a habit of posting the *actual* error message :)

Comment: Do not under any circumstances let us know the content of the error message because that would be like, you know, just too easy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice (which is embarrassing in retrospect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a subquery at all.  This just slows down the processing in MySQL (the optimizer is not very smart; it materializes subqueries losing index information).

```
SELECT ts.name As Status, AVG(DateDiff(t.created, now())) 
FROM sca_ticket t LEFT JOIN
     sca_ticket_status ts
     ON t.status_id = ts.id
GROUP BY ts.name
ORDER BY sort
```

Answer (score 1):

Try closing your second select statement

```
SELECT sca_ticket_status.name As Status, AVG(QueueTime) 
FROM (SELECT status_id, DateDiff (created, now()) as 'QueueTime'
FROM sca_ticket) q1
LEFT JOIN sca_ticket_status
ON q1.status_id = sca_ticket_status.id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY sort
```

You will also need to expose the status_id column in your inner select list if you want to join on it later.